# How to combine aggregate, join, and grouped by?

Tags: sql, oracle

table one:

```
dept-----job------salary  
01......nurse .....1000  
02......driver.....2000  
02......doctor.....5000  
01.......pilot.....2000
```

table two:

```
dept------location  
01..........Japan  
02..........New York
```

I'm trying to get the average salary for each job by location.

This is what I came up with (obviously incorrect)

```
SELECT two.location, one.job, AVG(one.sal)  
FROM one, two  
WHERE one.dept = two.dept  
GROUPED BY two.loc, one.job;
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (Apologies for awful table format)

Comment: what is your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
SELECT 
    B.location, A.job, AVG(A.salary)  
FROM 
  one AS A
  LEFT JOIN two  AS B
  ON A.dept = B.dept
GROUP By B.location, A.job
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ANSI JOIN syntax.

```
SELECT two.location, one.job, AVG(one.salary)
FROM one 
JOIN two
WHERE one.dept = two.dept
GROUP BY two.location, one.job;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be quite close to the result you're looking for.

- it is not `GROUPED BY`, but `GROUP BY`. Don't reinvent syntax, use a manual
- if you select `two.location`, you can't group by `two.loc` and expect it to work
- switch to modern joins (see below); nowadays, you shouldn't be using comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause. Join tables *explicitly*, put conditions (you might be using) into the `WHERE` clause. It helps in code readability, it is easier to maintain, will allow you to outer-join one table to more than only one another table (if necessary). With the syntax you use, that can't be done.

Here's an example of you might be doing it. CTE (the WITH factoring clause) just shows your data; *useful* code is from line 13 onwards.

```
SQL> with
  2  one (dept, job, salary) as
  3    (select '01', 'nurse' , 1000 from dual union all
  4     select '02', 'driver', 2000 from dual union all
  5     select '02', 'doctor', 5000 from dual union all
  6     select '01', 'pilot' , 2000 from dual
  7    ),
  8  two (dept, location) as
  9    (select '01', 'Japan'    from dual union all
 10     select '02', 'New York' from dual
 11    )
 12  -- This is what you need
 13  select t.location,
 14         o.job,
 15         avg(o.salary) avg_salary
 16  from one o join two t on t.dept = o.dept
 17  group by t.location,
 18           o.job
 19  order by t.location,
 20           o.job;

LOCATION JOB    AVG_SALARY
-------- ------ ----------
Japan    nurse        1000
Japan    pilot        2000
New York doctor       5000
New York driver       2000

SQL>
```

---

As you tagged the question with `oracle-apex` tag, I suggest you put a query into the **Interactive Report**, e.g.

```
select t.location, 
       o.job,
       o.salary
from one o join two t on t.dept = o.dept
order by t.location,
         o.job
```

and then examine its **Actions** button, which allows you to perform a number of different settings, which include sorting, calculating averages/summaries/etc., highlighting, ... Play around with it, I hope you'll find it interesting. A good thing in it is that users can create their own reports and save them for later. You'd provide only the basic query and layout, while each of them is free to modify it (without affecting the primary report; don't worry, they can't spoil anything).